# Using Selenium in Java to log in to hot or not and fetch photos

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to make a program (bot) that uses Selenium in java to login to http://us1.hotornot.com/.

I would like to log in with the "sign in with email" option on the webpage -- one hovers their mouse over a button with text "Or", then a drop-down set of options appear with an option "sign in with mail" and after clicking this a dialog box appears where one can enter their details (checking out the site should make it much clearer). I have trouble working out how to do open this dialog box and enter the data with selenium (although I know how to enter text in a textbox normally).

My intention is to then download user images (I think I can work out that part on my own) and use this data for a machine learning project -- many of the available image libraries do not have the specifications I need in addition to attractiveness ratings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Try something like this with an implicit wait before step 2. If it works let me know so I can write a formal Answer. I can't try it myself at the moment so it may not:

1) driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("btn btn--lg btn--white btn--more dropdown-link")).click();
2) driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.js-ovl-open.b-link")).click();

Comment: Thanks for the code; I tried it out, but unfortunately the first line gives me: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Returned node was not an HTML element. However, when I use the second line by itself I get no error, but I then try to execute: driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("emailaddress@eg.com");,  which gives me the same error. @JaneGoodall

Comment: If I'm following you correctly, now you can unreel the Or spinner, click on or hover over Sign in with Email, and open the sign in popup, but you can't send the popup your keys? Can you paste your code so far into pastebin and post the link here?

Comment: Sure: http://pastebin.com/X1C75nCc. If I understand the code you've given me correctly, since the first line does not work but the second does, it seems that I can click on the email button (#2 that you gave me) without unreeling the "Or" spinner, but simply using sendKeys afterwards to the email address textbox will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to click the checkbox on the lefthand side of the post to mark this as the accepted answer after you confirm it works.

```
public class Main {

    static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        hotOrNotLogin("emailAddress", "password");
    }

    public static void hotOrNotLogin(String emailAddress, String password) {

        final String OR_SPINNTER_CLASSNAME = "dropdown-link";
        final String SIGNUP_BY_EMAIL_CLASSNAME = "a.js-ovl-open.b-link";
        final String EMAIL_INPUT_NAME = "email";
        final String PASSWORD_INPUT_NAME = "password";
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 8);

        driver.get("http://hotornot.com/");

        //move cursor to the Or spinner to reveal the drop-down
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className(OR_SPINNTER_CLASSNAME)));
        WebElement orSpinner = driver.findElement(By.className(OR_SPINNTER_CLASSNAME));
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(orSpinner);
        actions.perform();

        //sign in with email
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(SIGNUP_BY_EMAIL_CLASSNAME)).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name(EMAIL_INPUT_NAME)).sendKeys(emailAddress);
        driver.findElement(By.name(PASSWORD_INPUT_NAME)).sendKeys(password + Keys.RETURN);

    }
}
```

I had to add some `wait.until`s in the "//sign in with email" to get it to work with HtmlUnitDriver. You may have to fiddle with timings depending on your computer and connection speed.

Also welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Note to testers: You should follow standard OOP and TDD principles. Keep your driver code in your /src/main and your JUnit code in your /src/test, etc. I purposefully wrote this in a main procedure so that the questioner could see what Selenium is doing without having to think about good coding conventions. I also rarely chain methods for the same reason.

Comment: No problem @user3165713! By the way I suggest looking up error messages when you code more. Sometimes they're unclear, for example, the one that was produced when trying to find an element by multiple class names. If an element has `class="foo bar"`,`By.className("foo")` works in Selenium but `By.className("foo bar")` does not because By.className can only take one class, but "foo bar" is two classes separated by a space.

Comment: I do try -- I think in this case it was more a problem of not having a clear idea of what I was doing or how to find elements by certain references. Using your code and fiddling with Firefox I've worked out how to find the names I need to select them with code (e.g. "a.js-..."), so I'm almost finished with the image/score fetcher :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you read the Hot or Not conditions of use regulations.  I would say you need to use a headless browser for this type of screen scraping.  Look into coding tests using Java language with [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).  You can also do it non-headless with standard Firefox webdriver but it would be a little slower.  Depends on what you are doing.   Schedule the job using Jenkins.

Comment: Aren't tests that use something other than the actual browser that your users will use invalid?